# SQL REAL 0 division causing interesting error on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, compilation, real-datatype

Found an interesting problem on SQL Server yesterday, try this:

```
DECLARE @a REAL = 0.0000
DECLARE @c DECIMAL (18,10) = 20754/3.45 -- this is 6015.6521730000
DECLARE @b DECIMAL (18,10) = 
CASE 
    WHEN 1 > 2 
        THEN @a / 100
    WHEN 1 = 2
        THEN 56
    ELSE @c
END

SELECT @b
```

It seems to be a problem with precision, and how the case statement is compiled. It can be easily remedied by casting the REAL @a to a decimal in the case statement, but as it's @c we're returning and the other cases should never be hit, it's a strange problem to come across. 
Anyone know enough about SQL compilation to explain this?

Comment: what the hell are you asking, i can't understand =)

Comment: The result is `6015.6523437500`, he expects `6015.6521730000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's down to [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), as detailed in the documentation

> [CASE] Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.100).aspx

You can break it entirely by adding the line

```
WHEN 1 = 3 then getdate()
```

There's a more detailed explanation [here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/subtleties-of-data-type-precedence)

I imagine that the compiler assumes that all cases may be possible (your example is of course deliberately perverse :) )

Comment: of course, the script that caused the error was too complex to point out what I needed to show though :S It's still wreaking havoc with our systems because someone set the decimal accuracy differently in a function >< Thanks for the article, makes sense now. Just thought it was quite interesting as the case it occurred in should have been skipped over and might help a few people with weird errors in future!

Answer (score 0):

**This is a wrong answer, see podiluska's answer for the right one.**

The type of the result of the case statement is the type of the first `then` clause.  So:

```
CASE 
    WHEN 1 > 2 
        THEN @a / 100
```

Makes the `case` result in the type of `@a`, a `real`.  Change this to:

```
CASE 
    WHEN 1 > 2 
        THEN cast(@a as decima(18,10)) / 100
```

To get the result as `decimal(18,10)`.

Comment: It's not the type of the *first* clause - order is irrelevant. If you swap the results to `when 1>2 then 12 when 1=2 then @a/100` it still returns a real type

Comment: @podiluska: interesting, i'll leave this answer here so other people who think this may see it's wrong

Comment: glad to have taught something to someone with such high SQL reputation :)